# No sound when embedding archive.org game

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed

I need to embed an internet archive game (archive.org) in an iframe inside a web page. The game in question looks good but I can't get it to have sound.

I leave you the link to the game:
https://archive.org/details/arcade_ckong

And this is the HTML test code:

```
<body>
<iframe src="https://archive.org/embed/arcade_ckong" width="560" height="384" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
```

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/rpeveri/pen/zYWOOVJ

Comment: embed version appears to be soundless, regardless of it running inside an iframe or on the origianal url: https://archive.org/embed/arcade_ckong

Comment: I have sound but I don't know how to activate it. from what I saw the sound is activated with a javascript but I don't understand how to do it in an iframe.

Comment: the javascript function to activate / deactivate sound is `AJS.emulator.setMute()`, but you cannot execute it inside the iframe, for security reasons (cross-origin).

Comment: uhhhh too bad. well, thank you very much anyway.